# Flexible table with overflown content hidden

Tags: css, overflow, css-tables

I have a table full of data that's typically pretty manageable, but on occasion we'll get a column with data that's incredibly long (usually a URL). Wrapping isn't an option as vertical space is more precious than horizontal.

The option I've proposed is to basically set a min-width on certain columns (to be flagged by the user), so if the user's browser is wide enough to handle it they will see the entire string, and if not they'll see a truncated version. I know the overflow property doesn't really work on table cells, but fortunately we already have all cell contents being wrapped in a `<div>` so I should be able to do this.

Here is a Fiddle with my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/nK9LA/

You'll see in the CSS I'm trying to set a `min-width` on the 5th column:

```
table th:nth-child(5),
table td:nth-child(5) {
    width: 1px; }
table th:nth-child(5) a,
table td:nth-child(5) span {
    background: rgb(180,180,180);
    min-width: 40px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

However, it's not working. I basically need that column to hide the overflown content (with a min-width of 40px) when the browser is too small to display the entire string.

Suggestions on how to pull this off?

Oh, and notice I don't have "Javascript" listed in my tags. :)

Comment: Evidently a lot of people are trying this. My first jsfiddle number was 7, and my second was 22. Or one person is just saving a lot of versions.

Comment: Haha! That's funny. I haven't updated it, so yeah, someone else is perplexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, change `min-width` to `max-width` to get the content to truncate: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/nK9LA/7/

UPDATE (since I did misunderstand):

I would use media queries to adjust a `width` or `max-width` setting at different browser widths. In this example, a `max-width: 100px;` is applied when the screen is less than 500px wide: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/nK9LA/22/embedded/result/

Media queries can be polyfilled for browsers that don't support with respond.js.

Comment: But it needs to be flexible with a min-width, not a max. If the browser is large enough, user should see the full string. If not, it should collapse, but not below the min-width of 40px.

Comment: Ah, so you want a fluid table cell width to not be less than 40px.

Comment: I wish there was a more elegant solution, but yeah... this is a fabulous idea. Thank you!

Comment: @BrandonDurham Yeah, I was curious to see what others might come up with. Perhaps this is it without involving javascript.